# If Naruto can creates one thousand clones, and sometimes he uses them to do his work, why does he always have a lot of work?

Tags: boruto

In Boruto, Boruto all the time complains about Naruto not being with him. And Naruto can create one thousand clones, and sometimes he creates a clone to do his work or to do an interview. Then, why doesn't he create dozens of clones to do his work and have time with his family?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And my future dream is to be the greatest Hokage! Then the whole village will stop disrespecting me and start treating me like I'm somebody. Somebody important!
> <sub>[Naruto Uzumaki](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Naruto_Uzumaki), *Naruto chapter 4*</sub>

Ever since the start of the original series, Naruto's goal was to become the greatest Hokage of the Leaf Village. From episode 1 of *Naruto* to episode 500 of *Naruto Shippuden*, Naruto spent his entire life gaining the trust and respect of his village, and eventually the entire nation.

Naruto did not want to be seen as a lazy Hokage. While he does on occasion use shadow clones to accomplish various tasks, an overuse of this could eventually turn south and the village elders potentially seeing Naruto as an incompetent leader and unable to handle tasks on his own.

Another reason for this is to look at the original design of shadow clones. Shadow clones can be deployed for intelligence and recon, and all gathered information is returned to the caster when the shadow clone is released. This was explained by Kakashi at one point.

However, based on various events in the series, it is apparent that if too much is going on between the caster and their shadow clones, the casters chakra can become imbalanced. Examples of this are during Naruto's wind nature training and his battle with Pain while having shadow clones in reserve. During the wind training, Kurama's chakra would sometimes leak and take over one of the clones and Naruto was limited on shadow clones during his fight with Pain.

My point above is that if Naruto tried to do too many administrative tasks at once, such as interviews, signing documents, battle strategies, planning Chunin exams, preparing teams for missions, etc... it could be information overload if all that knowledge hit the caster at once.

Answer (score 0):

Because for him being hokage was a dream that came true with continuous efforts and struggle ,He became hokage to do something good for his village which he considers as his family rather than sitting at home chilling, The clones tire him quickly, so this is the second reason, so if he uses clones to do all the work, that's rude and makes the viewer wonder? Why should he not rely on himself, and why did he want to be a Hokage if he was not relying on himself. Hope i answered the question.

Comment: Welcome to A&M! This does not really seem to answer the question asked. Which asks why he doesn't use shadowclones, so that he can do both. Could you perhaps elaborate a bit more as to why he wouldn't/couldn't.

Comment: Understandable! I have added some reasons.